# How to use process variables in Camunda-bpm?

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

I'm new to Camunda and didn't find any tutorial or reference explaining how to achieve the following:
I have a simple bpmn process in which I am using a service task. I want to execute my process by using processEngine.getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("Process_1", variables);
where my variables are as follows:

```
Map variables = new HashMap();
variables.put("a", 2);
variables.put("b", 5);
```

Now my service task is implementing a java class in which I want to use to process variables "a" and "b"?

How can I get the same process variables "a" and "b" in that class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your class implement JavaDelegate and add it as service delegate in the modeler. Then access the variable via the DelegateExecution instance camunda passes to the execute method.

```
public class MyServiceDelegate implements JavaDelegate {
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        execution.getVariable("a");
    }
}
```

This is very basic and for shure is covered in the getting started examples. Maybe a good idea to take a step back and study the fundamental concepts?